# File encoding for chinese

Tags: android, localization, file-encodings

I have my android application localized to english, czech and couple of other european languages. I would like to add chinese, japanese, korean and russian localizations. Is there any special way to do that in terms of **file encoding** and so on?

Comment: You mean other than using UTF-8?

Comment: I mean, if there is any special way... So if not, I just want somebody to confirm, that I can send english strings.xml to a translator with no modifications of file encoding and it will work when he replaces them with e.g chinese characters.

Comment: As long as they use an editor that honors the encoding, yes.